# CSS selector with :not does not behave as expected

Tags: python, css, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I want to use a CSS selector to select everything after the element with value SOUND WORD, but before the element with value called COMPONENTS using a CSS selector in Python.

```
<p class="p_cat_heading">SOUND WORD</p>
<p class="p_normal__and__avoid_page_break_after"><span class="c_tone_char">Vene</span><span class="c_tone_char__and__underline">zue</span><span class="c_tone_char">la</span> /<span class="calibre22">venedswela</span>/</p>
<p class="p_normal__and__avoid_page_break_after">South American country over the equator, known in part for its sunny beaches. Pronounce it in Italian for a better sound match.</p>
<p class="p_normal__and__avoid_page_break_after"><img width="30%" alt="" src="../images/00461.jpeg" class="calibre18"/></p>
<p class="p_cat_heading__and__centre_alignment">COMPONENTS</p>
```

I am using the following CSS selector:

```
content = str(soup.select_one('.p_cat_heading:contains("SOUND WORD") + :not(.p_cat_heading)'))  # type: str
```

This should select everything up to the element with class p_cat_heading. However it only selects:

```
<p class="p_normal__and__avoid_page_break_after"><span class="c_tone_char">Vene</span><span class="c_tone_char__and__underline">zue</span><span class="c_tone_char">la</span> /<span class="calibre22">venedswela</span>/</p>
```

I must misunderstand how the CSS selector is working. I thought `:` worked like a Python slice, but it appears to be that is not the case. That said, I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Replace `select_one` with `select`

Comment: That's not how the `+` operator in CSS works. `selector1 + selector2` matches an element that matches `selector2` that's immediately after one that matches `selector1`. It doesn't match all the elements in between.

Comment: @abdusco - Gave that a go and it doesn't work

Comment: @Barmar ah, that explains it! Is there a syntax then that gets you everything in between?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: This is generally done with higher-level operations in programming languages, like jQuery `.nextUntil()` and `.nextAll()`.

Comment: @Barmar - Ok, do you want me to leave the question open?

Edit: I'll work it out with one of the suggested solutions and post that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Barmar for the help on this one. To reiterate his comment, you can't do this with a CSS selector. Instead what I did was iterate over the elements until I reached the delimiter:

```
for temp_heading in heading.find_next_siblings():
    if temp_heading.attrs["class"][0] == "p_cat_heading":
        break
    else:
        print(str(temp_heading))
organized_entry["soundword"] = content
```

where temp_heading was an instance of bs.element.Tag which started by pointing at:

```
<p class="p_cat_heading">SOUND WORD</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is as you show you can use filtering and filter out the p tags that are either the second search string or following sibling from the sibling p tags of the first search string. This is quite specific to match what you are showing.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <p class="p_cat_heading">SOUND WORD</p> 
  <p class="p_normal__and__avoid_page_break_after"><span class="c_tone_char">Vene</span><span class="c_tone_char__and__underline">zue</span><span class="c_tone_char">la</span> /<span class="calibre22">venedswela</span>/</p> 
  <p class="p_normal__and__avoid_page_break_after">South American country over the equator, known in part for its sunny beaches. Pronounce it in Italian for a better sound match.</p> 
  <p class="p_normal__and__avoid_page_break_after"><img width="30%" alt="" src="../images/00461.jpeg" class="calibre18"></p> 
  <p class="p_cat_heading__and__centre_alignment">COMPONENTS</p>
 </body>
</html>
'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
result = [item.text.strip() for item in soup.select('p:contains("SOUND WORD") ~ p:not(p:contains("COMPONENTS") ~ p, p:contains("COMPONENTS"))')]
```